# Блокировка семафором с await

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, async-await

Вот такой код как ниже видел много раз. Кто-то говорит, что это нежелательный код и писать такие блокировки с await не следует, но я так и не смог уловить и до конца разобраться в проблеме.

Пожалуйста, не могли бы Вы объяснить, почему так не следует писать? И как в таком случае сделать блокировку безопасной?

```
public class Sample
    {
        private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

        public async Task DoSomethingThreadSafe()
        {
            await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                await ThreadSafeCode();
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphoreSlim.Release();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305825/semaphore-wait-vs-waitasync-in-an-async-method

Comment: @AzizUmarov Да, там описано, что обычный lock не работает с await, потому что выполнение может продолжиться в другом контексте, и что к семафору это не относится, что означает. видимо, что проблем нет. Однако где-то я видел, что и этот код - тоже нежелателен.

Comment: Ваш пример примерно такой я так понимаю https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/amp/

Comment: @AzizUmarov, верно, мой пример в точности такой) И я спрашиваю - насколько мой пример безопасен. Потому что я совершенно точно где-то встречался с мнением, что мой код и соответственно код по вашей ссылке - нежелателен) Я так понимаю, вы таким образом хотите сказать, что с моим кодом в целом все ок?)

Comment: _Кто-то говорит, что это нежелательный код и писать такие блокировки с await не следует_ Кто говорит? Как по мне, вполне нормальный код, и если у вас в этом месте  присутствуют I/O операции, пишите свободно так как указано выше. Нормальный паттерн. Если важна производительность или отсутствуют I/O операции, то выполняйте работу синхронно, но во отдельном потоке, здесь вам придет на помощь Producer/Consumer шаблон программирования. Для вашего вопроса очень важен контекст применения, но с очень большой вероятностью данный код вам подойдет, и проблем не будет.

Comment: @aepot увидел на днях в каком-то комментарии абстрактном, мол плохая практика, источник потерялся, а навязчивая мысль не давала покоя, учитывая сколько я такого понаписал) Да, там просто I/O операции по сути. Спасибо, просто нужно было мнение со стороны, а то спросить толком не у кого!

Comment: @AlexK. для обеспечения потокобезопасности есть еще такая штука как `SynchronizationContext`. По сути она и используется как UI поток в Winfoms/WPF приложениях. Можно создать свой контекст синхронизации, то есть грубо говоря под определенный тип операций выделить отдельный поток, и просто в него инвокать все что нужно. Так как все нужные дела будут выполняться в одном контексте синхронизации, семафор не потребуется. Штука не суперпростая, но как минимум для расширения кругозора рекомендую вникнуть: [ссылка](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/).